# press a key to boot up windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, keyboard

Hard disk crashed on sony vaio laptop, so I replaced it. fresh install of windows 7. every thing is ok, but when laptop is powered on, windows is starting shows up, and stops form a couple of minutes, and start again displaying the windows logo. normal boot up can continue when I press any key on keyboard. Can this be fixed. all drivers all installed.

Answer (score 0):

When the laptop first boots up, right after BIOS hit F8 key. You will get a lot of boot options, select the option "Boot Windows Normally". That should fix it. If not then repeat and choose "Load Good Last Known Configuration".